# Find a string after two other strings with something between them

Tags: regex

Let's go with an example:

"Blablabla. My name is John and I'm 21 years old. Blablabla"

Other example:

"Blablabla. My name is John and I'm 21 years old.
- Hi I'm Mary and I'm 22 years old."

Basically, I want to match the age of the first person (here, 21, it could be 23 or whatever). The idea is that I know I'll have a sentence beginning with "My name is $name and I'm 21" but I can't afford to know what is $name. 
The gross idea is to select a number after "My name is "+something+" and I'm ".

How one would do that with a regex, knowing that I can't use catch groups?

What I have so far:

```
    (?<=<My name is )(.*)(?= years old)
```

Ideally I would like something like that to work:

```
    (?<=<My name is .* and I'm )(.*)(?= years old)
```

... but it does not! .* can't be in a look ahead group apparently (which makes some sense).

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Have you tried to construct the regex yourself? Please post what you've tried and the behavior of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/My name is (\w+) and I'm (\d+) years old./
```

Now the first matched group is the name, the second matched group is the age.

---

If for some reason you don't want to use groups, you can match:

```
/(?<=My name is )\w+(?= and I'm )/
```

for the name and:

```
/(?<= and I'm )\d+(?= years old.)/
```

for the age.

---

As you have noticed, lookbehinds with variable length are not allowed (at least in the regex engines that I know of, not that it is logically impossible). However, you can use `\K` as an alternative:

```
/My name is \w+ and I'm \K\d+(?= years old.)/
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I try this I match the whole sentence. I just want to match 21.

Comment: Thanks again.Nevertheless I really need the considered sentence to start with "My name is". Sorry if I seem pushy, I don't mean to.

Comment: You definitely worked hard enough for this one. I'll give you the upvote that the OP didn't offer.

Comment: You're really cute for making look like such a b***** Joe but I don't have enough reputation to give him an upvote ;). Ndn, thank you agin very much.

Comment: @user1785671, well if it worked for you, could you please accept the answer as correct. :)

Comment: Yup, I couldn't check until now: I just did, and it works just fine. Perfect. Thank you very much. I didn't know ths \K stuff! Imma accept the answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

@ndn's answer is basically correct, but I think it needs a couple of modifications:

1. The `\w+` expression will not find spaces, such as in "My name is **Mary Kate** and I'm 47 years old."
2. If I'm interpret your request correctly that you need only the date to match, then I don't think the lookbehind and lookaround assertions that you and @ndn have set up are necessary.

I believe this regex will give you what you want:
`My name is .+? and I'm (\d+) years old\.`

(Note the `\.` at the end so it will match the literal period, rather than any character.)

See example at https://regex101.com/r/nJ7wS5/1

Comment: Thanks. But the capturing group (\d+) doesn't seem to be an option for me :/. So the regex you proposed matches the whole sentence. I'll edit my question to add the fact that I can't use catching groups.